# How to get SQL Query Error Details when QueryTable.Refresh fails

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Say I have this simple bit of VBA that refreshes a query table:

```vb
With aListObject.QueryTable
    .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

If the above table returns an error from the SQL engine upon refreshing, then how do I obtain the actual SQL error details?

E.g. I want this type of message, which is returned in SQL Server Management Studio:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> Divide by zero error encountered.

I can add error handling to the VBA to return the VBA error as such:

```vb
On Error Resume Next    
With aListObject.QueryTable
    .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    if err.number > 0 then msgbox err.Description
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

But this only returns this message:

> SQL Syntax Error

How do I return the full SQL error message details?

I have looked at the following but can't find anything that jumps out there:

- `QueryTable` object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable)
- `QueryTable.Refresh` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.refresh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return specific errors from connected ODBC driver, consider building QueryTable from an ADO recordset that processes the SQL prior to passing into QueryTable. As [`QueryTables` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytables.add) indicate, the *connection* argument can take a variety of forms including recordsets (and even the example in docs shows how such ADO recordset connection):

> The data source for the query table can be one of the following:
>
> - A string containing an OLE DB or ODBC connection string. The ODBC connection string has the form `ODBC;<connection string>`.
> - A QueryTable object from which the query information is initially copied, including the connection string and the SQL text, but not
>     including the Destination range. Specifying a QueryTable object causes
>     the Sql argument to be ignored.
> - An ADO or DAO Recordset object. Data is read from the ADO or DAO recordset. Microsoft Excel retains the recordset until the query table
>     is deleted or the connection is changed. The resulting query table
>     cannot be edited.
>
> ...

---

Adjusted VBA with  error handling:

```vb
Sub Get_SQL_Data()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sqlstring As String, connstring As String

    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    connstring = "Driver={SQL Server}; ..."
    conn.Open connstring

    ' OPEN RECORDSET
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    rst.Open sqlstring, conn

    With Worksheets("MAIN").QueryTables.Add( _
           Connection:=rst, _
           Destination:=Range("A1"))
       .Name = "SQL_DATA"
       .FieldNames = True
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    rst.Close: conn.Close

ExitHandle:
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. Using the ABO connection seems a good way to get the error message before inserting the recordset into the querytable.Thanks!